# Error: #1436 - Thread stack overrun with MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Given error:  #1436 - Thread stack overrun:  6024 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `After_delete_area_package`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `After_delete_area_package` AFTER DELETE ON `area_package`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN    
DELETE FROM accounts_areas
WHERE (area_id = 1); 
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

simple as hell i would guess. 
The only area_id in table accounts_areas is 1
Before that i tried old.package_area_id

I do not have foreign key restraints and my overhead goes red in phpMyAdmin set to 28B.

RDMS: myISAM

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79a41

Question: Why would my trigger not delete all the rows from accounts_areas where area_id = 1

Comment: sample data or table schema or i personally feel sqlfiddle with some real data would allow SO users to solve questions in seconds ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you perhaps be missing an `END`?

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS After_delete_area_package;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER After_delete_area_package AFTER DELETE ON area_package
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM accounts_areas
    WHERE area_id = 1;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

**Edit 1**

Since you are reviving a `thread_stack` error, the solution would would be to increase the stack size.

Comment: Forgot to copy that. Edited to the above, still not working. I am deleting the row from my backend

Comment: Do you receive any errors? What is the result of `SELECT * FROM accounts_areas WHERE area_id = 1`? Try including adding the database (`...TRIGGER db.After_delete...`)

Comment: The error i get when removing the row in phpMyAdmin  #1436 - Thread stack overrun:  6024 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

Comment: @NielsAulman See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821575/mysql-error-1436-thread-stack-overrun-with-simple-query), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376725/how-do-i-resolve-a-mysql-thread-stack-overrun) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021945/why-does-this-mysql-trigger-cause-a-stack-overflow) for possible resolutions to the error.

Comment: I have manualy edited the my.cnf to 256kb but. The query now works but the downside is that i lost my insert in phpMyAdmin. Bit weird

Comment: Ok i lost most functionality in phpMyAdmin